# Maven exclude resources not working as expected

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to exclude from a build **all** YAML resource files, **but** the ones with a *prod* clause within the filename.
For example, given that my resource directory contains *application-dev.yaml*, *application-test.yaml* and *application-prod.yaml*, I would like *application-dev.yaml* and *application-test.yaml* to be excluded and *application-prod.yaml* to be kept.

The portion of my POM that deals with the resources is below:

```xml
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*-!(prod).yaml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/web/WEB-INF</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
```

However, exclusion does not work and **all** YAML files are copied, including *application-dev.yaml* and *application-test.yaml*.
I tested the exclusion pattern in Bash shell by `ls *-!(prod).yaml` and it worked as expected.

At this point I am lost and am looking for the community assistance.
I thank you all in advance for your thoughts and comments.

Comment: Have you taken a look into the documentation? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: @khmarbaise The point is that a complex exclusion pattern does not work.
If I simplify the pattern to be _*.yaml_ rather than _*-!(prod).yaml_, the exclusion works perfectly. I could have gone by excluding everything, and including the desired files - it is less elegant, because I have to mention explicitly _log4j2.xml_ and so on. I am trying to make the complex pattern to work...

Comment: Maven-resources-plugin uses ant based patterns which doesn't support '!'.

Comment: @Ramu It was a valuable point, hence I switched to regex as Ant supports regex patterns. I changed the exclusion pattern to a regex form _^.+\-((?!prod).)*\.yaml$_, tested the pattern in Notepad++; however, Maven still does not exclude the files...

Comment: @Lev Ant does support regex patterns but the Ant's Fileset patterns only supports `*, ** and ?` and Maven resource plugin also uses the same patterns. Please refer following links for more details. [Ant Fileset](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Apache_Ant/Fileset) [ DirectoryScanner used by Maven plugin](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-utils/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/util/DirectoryScanner.html)

Comment: I suppose you are running a spring boot app. As a resolve I would use the other profiles only for development or tests which means they should belong to `src/test/resources` .

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve that I would go with maven profiles and resource plugin [maven resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)
You can have variables to the resource file name according to what you need (prod, dev, etc)